# 301 URL Redirect with arguments without htaccess or php

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

How do I redirect `http://olddomain.com/page` to `http://newdomain.com/page`

The old domain is using namecheap's dns. Currently, I have setup a 301 URL redirect on `olddomain.com` and `www.olddomain.com` to `www.newdomain.com`. However, visiting `olddomain.com/page`  takes me to `www.newdomain.com` instead of `www.newdomain.com/page`.

Is there a way to do it without using htaccess or php?

Answer (score 0):

use webmaster tool. Thats is easy. We normaly use server side programming, ip redirect. But that is very easy and convenient.

Comment: Which webmaster tool? Please clarify.